# Bootstrap Panel : Text and plus symbol on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Panel. In that, I have a text to the left side and a **+** symbol to the right side. When I want to increase the font-size of **+** symbol then panel heading gets extra height.

I don't want to increase font-size of left side text. but **+** symbol to be litter bigger than left side text.

```css
.add_discount_plus_minus {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel panel-default set_margin_0 set_padding_0 no_box_shadow" >
  <div class="panel-heading text-left ">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <span>Add Discount</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer add_discount_plus_minus ">+</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Would like to have a panel heading like this]

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: I know this isn't a solution to your problem, but honestly man that looks fine to me. I'd maybe change the color of the background on the header a little bit (but I'm colorblind so take that with a grain of salt)

Comment: plus symbol is getting down in the panel. how can I make it in a line with left text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to vertical align the symbol, absolute positioning and transform, with container's height at any size:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```css
.add_discount_plus_minus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel panel-default set_margin_0 set_padding_0 no_box_shadow">
  <div class="panel-heading text-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span>Add Discount</span>
        <span class="cursor_pointer add_discount_plus_minus">+</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

added some properties to ypur class

```
.add_discount_plus_minus {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```css
.add_discount_plus_minus {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel panel-default set_margin_0 set_padding_0 no_box_shadow" >
  <div class="panel-heading text-left ">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <span>Add Discount</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer add_discount_plus_minus ">+</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use line-height in css

```css
.add_discount_plus_minus{
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:20px;
}
 #discount{
  line-height:50px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel panel-default set_margin_0 set_padding_0 no_box_shadow" >
<div class="panel-heading text-left ">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                            <span id="discount">Add Discount</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                            <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer add_discount_plus_minus ">+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: plus symbol is getting down. I want it to be on the same line